# Change field css in listMapper Sonata Admin

Tags: php, bundle, sonata

I want to modify style for "benefice" field in listMapper.

```
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('date')
            ->add("nombreMatch")
            ->add('cote')
            ->add('mise')
            ->add('gain')
            ->add('benefice',null,array(
            'attr' => array('style' => 'color:red;'),
            ));
    }   
}
```

I use "attr" attribute but it does work.I also try "header_style" attribute and It does work.

If somebody has solution,

Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom tempalate in 3rd parameter, like I did [here](https://github.com/kunicmarko20/SimpleConfigurationBundle/blob/v1.x/Admin/ConfigurationAdmin.php#L33) or you can try and pass `header_style` instead of `attr` as explained [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_list.html#visual-configuration).

Comment: @zbeb try header style instead of attr?

Comment: @zbeb I updated my answer with a link to docs, that should help you.

Comment: it doesn't work :    ->add('benefice',null,array(
            'attr' => array('header_style', 'color:red'))
            )

Comment: ->add('benefice',null,array( 'header_style' => 'color:red') )  @zbeb

Comment: I dont want to custome header, but data in list :)

Comment: @zbeb did you try using template?

Comment: If i don't find solution, i will use template. But i want just custome color text

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, thanks !

For other people who have same problems :

```
 protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14%',    
            ])
            ->add('date', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14%',    
            ])
            ->add("nombreMatch", null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14%',    
            ])
            ->add('cote', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14%',    
            ])
            ->add('mise', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14%',    
            ])
            ->add('gain', null ,[
                'header_style' => 'width: 14%',    
            ])
           ->add('benefice', null, array('template' => '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/Special/benefice_field_list.html.twig'))
        ;
    }

{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field%}
    <div>
        <strong>{{ object.benefice }}</strong>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```